# CodeIgniter/jQuery - Ajax call returns full html page instead of my echo

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

In my view I have an ajax call:

```
    $(".previous").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "planner/get_cal",
            data: {current_month: current_month},
            success: function(msg){
                alert(msg);
            }

        });
```

the get_cal function in my Planner controller:

```
function get_cal()
{
    echo "dinosaurs";
}
```

However, instead of returning "dinosaurs", it returns a full HTML page. I can't figure out why. Thoughts? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have a layout tied to your controller that would render it?

Comment: what do you get when you try manually from a browser ?

Comment: @krishna, going to the get_cal page manually gets me a blank page with "dinosaurs", as expected.

Comment: Have you tried adding a leading slash? `url: "/planner/get_cal",`

Comment: What does firebug show? Is it a 404 ?

Comment: I second the leading / -- Otherwise things look just fine, and this shouldn't be happening.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved this by using a leading slash as suggested in the comments to my question.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/planner/get_cal",
  dataType: "text",
  data: {current_month: current_month},
  success: function(msg){
    alert(msg);
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also get it by adding exit after echo in your php file like below:

```
function get_cal()
 {
    echo "dinosaurs";exit;
}
```

It will work. :)

Comment: this works right now. I changed `exit` for `return` though, :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the dataType to "text"

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "planner/get_cal",
  data: {current_month: current_month},
  dataType: "text",
  success: function(msg){
      alert(msg);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the CodeIgniter structure of Controler/Method uri segments I've found it much easier to use ../../controller/method as my URL's in jquery ajax requests. I also recommend specifying a dataType so that the string is parsed and returned as an object.

Here is an example;

```
$.ajax({  
     type: "POST",  
     dataType: "json",  
     url: "../../controller/method",  
     success: mySuccessFunction  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is using the Zend Framework, I was experiencing the same issues where the AJAX response was returning the full HTML instead of the `json_encode()` response.  This was resolved by adding the following to my controller:

```
    if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest())
    {
        $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

These type of problem come when your php file and html file are not on proper path so that apache server could parse php files.
Without mentioning type:'text' and any other format also, ajax will work.
But be sure that your server is reaching to php file. Otherwise whole file will be treated as text and returned.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to mention:
the url will really depend on how you have your .htaccess and folder structure set-up.
So the best way is to try several urls, i.e.:
../../controller/method
../controller/method
server_folder/index.php/controller/method
http://example.com/server_folder/index.php/controller/method
and then choose the one that works best in a given situation.

Answer (score 0):

**// Main Page view**

```
$("#button").click(function(e)
{
  value=$("#input_value").val();

  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>path",
  data: "type=get_path_details&mobile="+value,
  cache: true,
  dataType:"html",
  async: false,
  success: function(data)
  {
  $('.apend_new_div').empty().append(data);
  $('.scroll_card').css('overflow-x','scroll');
  }
  });

});
```

**// Controller**

```
public function path()
{   
  $id = $this->input->post("mobile");
  // Some function goes here
  // $template[''] = ;
  $this->load->view('ajax_page',$template);
}
```

**// ajax view page**

```
<?php if($_POST['type']=='get_path_details'){if(!empty($template)){ ?>
// Html code 
<?php }} ?>
```