# How can I update my session scoped data model in a front controller java servlet web app page, without reloading the web page?

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets, front-controller

I have a MVC- structured web application. I have both `application-`, `session-`, and `request` scoped data, And I use a custom made Request Based MVC framework, similar to the ones in Spring and Struts. I have used [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications) as a tutorial.

I have a java object called `ShowModel`, which is passed as session scoped data. I use this to keep track of the users selection of visible components on the webpages.

All of the possible visibility selections are represented by a checkbox. They are all set to default of visible/checked when first setting the session data.

I have a listener on all of the checkboxes, that registers change, by class name "toggle", and sends it's id and `checked`/`unchecked` status by ajax to the server/servlet. See code example 1. I want to state that my experience with ajax is very limited.

As all of my calls are intercepted by my Front Controller Servlet, I needed to make a corresponding action, to execute the ajax `POST`-request. This code has been successfully reached, and executed. See code example 2.

My issue, however, **is that my action pattern forces redirections**. And in some mysterious way, **the ajax object responsetext turns out to be the entire html** of my index page.

My **datamodel is already updated**, but as it turns out, this is a faulty approach, due to the front controller strategy pattern.

So does anyone know of a way I can update my session scoped object's variables, without reloading the entire page?

**Code example 1**

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $('.toggle').change(function() {        
            var id = this.value;
            var checked = this.checked; 

            var json = new Object();
            json.id = id;
            json.checked = checked;

            $.ajax({
                    url: "selectionmodelupdate",
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: JSON.stringify(json),
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    mimeType: 'application/json',

                    success: function (data) {
                        $('.event').each(function (index, event) {
                            //Here I will put code, to update the ".event"'s to be visible or not

                        }); 
                    },
                    error:function(data,status,er) {
                        console.log(arguments);
                        alert("error: "+data+" status: "+status+" er:"+er);
                    }
            });

        });
    });
});
```

**Code Example 2**

```
    public class SelectionModelUpdateAction implements Action {

    @Override
    public String execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        ShowModel showModel = (ShowModel) session.getAttribute("showmodel");
        AppData appData = AppData.getInstance();
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); 

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));
        String json = "";
        if(br != null){
            json = br.readLine();
        }

        JsonObject jsonobject = new JsonParser().parse(json).getAsJsonObject();    
        boolean checked = jsonobject.get("checked").getAsBoolean();

        String id = jsonobject.get("id").getAsString();

        if(id.equals("A")){
            showModel.setASelected(checked);
            response.getWriter().write("{isSuccess: true}");
            return "index";
        }
        else if (id.equals("B")){
            showModel.setBSelected(checked);
            response.getWriter().write("{isSuccess: true}");
            return "index";
        }
        else if (id.equals("C")){
            showModel.setCSelected(checked);
            response.getWriter().write("{isSuccess: true}");
            return "index";
        }
        response.getWriter().write("{isSuccess: false}");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Comment: add `/` to ajax url like: `url: "/selectionmodelupdate"`

Comment: @Rembo Would you mind telling me what that is supposed to do? I can tell you that the single word url is intercepted by my front controller (see pattern in link in question), and a strategy-pattern based action library is accessed. In other words selectionmodelupdate is a string that I use as a key, when accessing a hashmap of action-classes. Changing the url to `/selectionmodelupdate` only gives me a "not found" error.

Comment: some answer have posted in SO that adding `/` in beginning of url value **solved responsetext turns out to be the entire html issue** [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637539/codeigniter-jquery-ajax-call-returns-full-html-page-instead-of-my-echo) , i thought it may help you.

Comment: Thanks for trying :)
I have spent a day solving this problem in an entirely different way. No Ajax at all, and my functionality works as I want it. The question is probably to big and specific to help anyone else, so I might delete it in a while.

Thanks anyway for trying :)